# Proof of the associative property of addition

Tags: proof-verification, logic, proof-writing

I am a high school student interested in propositional logic. I have been studying many examples and decided to attempt to write my own. I feel like it's very badly done and would appreciate some feedback. (This is the first propositional proof I have EVER written, I came up with the problem myself and I am aware it's not original and very basic.)

**Prove that $$P+Q+R = P+(Q+R)$$**

**My Proof:**

$1.$ $\mathrm Let$ $$P=7, Q=8, R=9$$
$2.$ $$P+Q+R=24$$
$3.$ $$Q+R=17$$ $$So$$ $$P+(Q+R) = 24$$
$4.$ $$Therefore$$ $$P+Q+R = P+(Q+R)$$

Comment: It seems you are giving one example, but you need to prove the general case.  You might start with identifying your definition of $P+Q+R$ (i.e., by this do you mean $(P+Q)+R$?) and the manipulations you are allowed to do.

Comment: Do you mean something like: Assume P, Q, and R are integers?

Comment: You tell me.  I don't know what you are trying to prove.  Are $P, Q, R$ integers? real numbers? matrices?

Comment: I'm trying to prove the associative property of addition. P, Q, and R are integers. They can be positive or negative.

Comment: What axioms are you allowed to work with?

Comment: The associative axiom of addition: for any integers $$k, m, n$$ we have $$(k+m)+n = k+(m+n)$$ I'm not sure if any others would be necessary.

Comment: So you are trying to prove the associativity axiom by using the associativity axiom?

Comment: Oh...that's a little circular. :/

Comment: Note that $P+Q+R$ doesn't strictly speaking mean anything, you have to specify whether you mean $(P+Q)+R$ or $P+(Q+R)$. It's only *because* addition is associative that we allow ourselves to drop the parentheses.

Comment: Ok, so it would have to be $$(P+Q)+R = P+(Q+R)$$ in order to prove the property. I'm trying to prove that I can solve this problem without the parentheses?

Comment: I know this comment chain is getting lengthy, so I think I need to step back and reassess what it is I am proving. Thanks for the help, it has shed some light on the things I haven't fully understood yet.

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16 You may benefit more from [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77749/room-for-captainamerica16-et-al).

Comment: I've never used the chat. Would you be willing to provide some more support there?

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16 Sure.

Comment: I think I might have sorted the proof out while I was waiting. I'll present it in the chat. When you are ready, feel free to confirm your presence there. I clicked the link you posted.

Comment: It is not propositional logic but first-order logic; with it **and** the [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) (see your second post) that defines *sum* you can prove *associativity* of $+$.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong. When of comes to logic, showing a specific case is not enough to prove something. Showing many cases is not enough either. To prove of you have to either show it's a direct consequence of definition or a consequence of something that was already proven. There are various proof techniques you can use.
You could probably start working your way from the definition of addition as the recursive application of the successor function S(n).

Comment: Yes, someone provided me a lot of assistance regarding this. My new task is to try and prove 1a = a, that is S(0)*a = a.